# dynamically adjust div background image width

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="ndnmpricetag-container"><div class="ndnmpricetag price">15.00$</div></div>

<div class="ndnmpricetag-container"><div class="ndnmpricetag">500000.00$</div></div>
```

`ndnmpricetag-container` use a static `background` image. When using large numbers (like the second example), the image is too small for the numbers.

How can i adjust `ndnmpricetag-container`'s `background` width depending on the `width` of `ndnmpricetag` ?

Full css and examples [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNGGxm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make following changes:

1. Change the `display` property of `.ndnmpricetag-container` to `inline-block` so that it doesn't take all of the width of block. To make `div` place in next line, use `< br/>` tag in HTML.
2. Give the `.ndnmpricetag-container` a `min-width` equal to the `image width` say `100px`. This will ensure that the image will not get cropped for very small widths.
3. Give `background-size:100% 100%;`.
4. Give `padding-right: 35px;`to  `.tondnmpricetag` so that the arrows at the end of your image are able to contain the numbers and text have enough space to adjust within image.

See the [updated link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXQQQL)

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Hi now try to this Css**

```
.ndnmpricetag-container {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 53px;
    background: url('http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/pricetag.png');
    background-size: 100% 54px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.ndnmpricetag-container {
text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 53px;
    background: url('http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/pricetag.png');
    background-size: 100% 54px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 7px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ndnmpricetag {
position: relative; 
top: 7px; 
margin-left: 7px;
margin-right: 7px;
font-face: Helvetica;
font-size:1.2em;
white-space: nowrap;
letter-spacing: -1px;
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="ndnmpricetag-container"><div class="ndnmpricetag price">15.00$</div></div>

<div class="ndnmpricetag-container"><div class="ndnmpricetag price">500000.00$</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a long image and use the 'Sliding door technique'.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/

Answer (score 0):

You can have `:before` pseudo element to contain start of element, `:after` to contain end of element. And self element contains repeated middle background.

```css
.a {
  background: url('http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/pricetag.png') repeat-x left center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 35px;
}
.a:before {
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/pricetag.png') no-repeat left center;
}
.a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 35px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  background: url('http://www.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/images/pricetag.png') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">15464%</a>
```